# OPC client trying to connect to OPC HDA server and end up in infinite waiting

Tags: connectivity, timeout

I am quite new to OPC server/client. I have a service application serves as an OPC client, and trying to connect to OPC HDA server to data reading.

There is a list of tags which their value at a particular timestamp are to be read from OPC HDA server. My service will loop through the list of the tags. For each tag, it will do the following:

- connect to OPC HDA server based on the URL link given
- Read the tag attributes from HDA server
- disconnect from OPC HDA server

My code is as follows:

Public Shared Function GetOPCTagInfo(m_Tstamp As Object, m_tagname As Object, TagItemid As Object, serverurl As Object)
On Error Resume Next
Dim d(6) As String 'an array to store tag attributes read from OPC server

```
    Dim KnownURL As URL = New URL

    KnownURL = New URL(serverurl)

    
    Dim server As Opc.Server = SampleClient.Factory.GetServerForURL(KnownURL)
    myserver = server
    myserver.Connect()
    

    If myserver.IsConnected Then
        
        d = newgetopcinfo(m_Tstamp, TagItemid, n) 'a function to read the item attributes from OPC server'
        
        myserver.Disconnect()

        Return d
    Else
            Return {"Fail to connect to server"}

    End If


End Function
```

Currently I have encountered the issue that, when my service tries to connect to the HDA server in order to read the data for the tags, it got hang. I suspect that when it tries to connect to HDA server (myserver.Connect() ), it does not receive any response from HDA server and end up in infinite waiting.

Is there anyway to break this infinite waiting, so that at least it can go to next tag to repeat the process, or try to re-connect?

Comment: Maybe if you showed us the commands that  are being sent to the database by logging every statement on a test system, we might be able to be of assistance. All you've told us is that two things happen, and then your system hangs when a third thing happens - it's a bit vague - more detail required.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. i have updated my question. hopefully it is clearer now